# How to parse an unconventional file with Talend?

Tags: parsing, talend

I have a file shape like this :

[image]

How can I parse a file like this with Talend Open Studio ?

Here's what I tried :

[image]

In the tJavaRow, the input is the whole file in a single row. I split it and parse it manually. But I can't figure out how to create an output row for each OBJ in the file.

Is this the "Right" way of doing it ? Or is there a specific component for this type of files ?

Comment: This could be done with a tJavaRow. Is the amount of key/value rows always the same? Is the comment important? Does it say "comment" or will this actually be a comment?

Comment: The amount of key/value is always the same, and the comment is an actual comment (generally a whole sentence). Ideally, I need to change one or two value in the file WITHOUT touching the rest of the file at all.

Answer (score 3):

> But I can't figure out how to create an output row for each OBJ in the file

You can do this by using the tJavaFlex component:

1. Put your raw content in the globalMap by connecting it to tFlowToIterate
2. Put your split-and-parse logic in the **"Start Code"** part of tJavaFlex, using the contents you made available in step 1
3. Start a loop in the **"Start Code"** part of tJavaFlex (e.g. for each object)
4. Define your output schema in tJavaFlex
5. In the **"Main Code"** part of tJavaFlex, map your parsed object to the columns of your output row
6. Dont forget to close your loop in the **"End Code"** part of tJavaFlex

I layed out a quick example, with no parsing logic. But since you already got this down, I think it should be sufficient:
[image: demo flow]

**Start Code**

```
String[] lines = ((String)globalMap.get("row1.content")).split("\r\n");
for(String line : lines) { // starts the "generating" loop
```

**Main Code**

```
    row2.key = line; // uses the "generating" loop
```

**End Code**

```
} // closes the "generating" loop
```